# I am confused to why my python guessing game is not working properly when I ask to play again

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get it to ask for me to play again and only accept y or n but I am confused as to why it is not working correctly. I am also getting the count value wrong as I am trying to break out of the while loop answer when I have the answer correct.

```
#Guessing game
import random
def guess():
    playAgain = 'y'
    while playAgain != 'n' and playAgain != 'no':
        if playAgain == 'y' or playAgain == 'yes':
            randomNum = random.randint(1, 2)
            answer = 'false'
            count = 0
            while answer != 'true':
                count = count + 1
                print("Can you guess the random number?")
                guess = int(input())
            
                if guess > randomNum:
                    print("Too high, guess again.")

                if guess < randomNum:
                    print("Too low, guess again.")

                if guess == randomNum:
                    print("You guessed the number! It too you " + str(count) + " tries.")
                    answer == 'true'
                    print("Do you want to play again? (y or n)")
                    playAgain= input()
        else:
            print("You must enter y or n")
            print("Do you want to play again? (y or n)")
            playAgain= input()


guess()
print("Thank you for playing.")
```

Comment: Typo: `answer == 'true'` should be `answer = 'true'`

Comment: why set it to a string? Set `answer=True` and test `if (not) answer:`

Answer (score 1):

At first glance there are two easy fixes;

1. You can fix the typo at line 23: `answer = 'true'`
2. You can add `if playAgain == "n": break` at line 26 (below `playAgain= input()`)